# Referencing a resource in a ResourceDictionary from a different ResourceDictionary in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I have the following set of code in my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Theme/Brushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Theme/Fonts.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Theme/CoreStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Theme/SdkStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Theme/MyAppName.xaml"/>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Controls/NavigationPanel.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The **NavigationPanel.xaml** contains a style that looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationPanelListBox" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBackground}" />
    <Lots of XAML>
</Style>
```

The **{StaticResource DarkBackground}** is defined in the **Brushes.xaml** file (i.e. the first resource dictionary).  It is defined as

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBackground" Color="#FF707176" />
```

in the resource dictionary.

At runtime, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key DarkBackground [Line: 16 Position: 44]
```

The line numbers and position references the **NavigationPanel.xaml** resource dictionary in the app.xaml.

I can reference the brush from other controls, just not the included resource dictionary.

Why can I not reference or why does it not resolve the reference to a resource that is higher in the heirarchy of the merged resource dictionary??  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you referencing the `DarkBackground` brush in any of the resources in the `NavigationPanel` dictionary?

If you are you might need to merge the `Brushes` resource dictionary into the `NavigationPanel` dictionary.

So in the **NavigationPanel** dictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.Common;component/Theme/Brushes.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: This does work and I understand why it resolves now but why does it not resolve when it is in the higher level dictionary?  I am marking your answer as correct, but I would love an explanation if you know why this is.

Comment: Found this in another thread. Leaving here for posterity. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/2be9a5f6-5313-448d-a9d9-296bac42215e/using-style-defined-in-merged-dictionary-from-another-merged-dictionary?forum=wpdevelop Thanks and credit to Kamil Nieweglowski for this.

Answer (score 9):

You can include one dictionary in another (like 'using' in C#) like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
    xmlns:uriMapper="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:APC.IKM.UI.SL.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Fonts.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="CoreStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Is this what you are looking for? The Cosmopolitan / Metro project template has a good example of this...

Answer (score 0):

the trully answer is Eric's answer in this site: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/2be9a5f6-5313-448d-a9d9-296bac42215e/using-style-defined-in-merged-dictionary-from-another-merged-dictionary?forum=wpdevelop.

the Brushes.xaml and the NavigationPanel.xaml is parsed independently and then added to the merged dictionary of Application resources so they don't know anything about each other.